# how to setup developer team environment in visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I need to know how to setup a developer team environment for asp.net . At present i am using visual studio 2008 . What kind of the things i need as requirements .

Comment: What are your goals?  What do you need that VS doesn't provide?

Comment: Four Developers need to develop a project as a team. How i share the working environment , database and reports ? . Thats It

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A team *must* have some way to co-ordinate their work. To do this a code repository is essential, and most teams use revision control software to manage this repository.

Without this in place you'll last less than a week before someone overwrites someone else changes with no way to reconcile the differences.

There are many good options and a few great ones: personally I like Subversion as it's open source, well maintained and well supported. Others include Microsoft's own Team Foundation Services (TFS) which is deeply integrated into Visual Studio Professional and above; this, however, most certainly is not free!

You may also want to consider systems such as Git and Mercurial.

TFS also includes bug tracking and task management functions. A small team may not need to use this to start with, but after your software has been installed then this can be very useful to keep track of what's where. Alternatives include Bugzilla and FogBugz.

For testing, you'll need a "staging" server that matches the configuration of the eventual server to which you'll deploy. If you're deploying to a cloud environment such as Azure or EC2 it's easiest to set up a second deployment environment there and use that.

Add to this a good backup solution for the code repository and test databases, and a decent network connection so your developers have access to this site, and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

the below link is a guide which shows you how to make the most of **Team Foundation Server**. It starts with the end in mind, but shows you how to incrementally adopt TFS for your organization. It's a collaborative effort between patterns & practices, Team System team members

[TFS Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> Four Developers need to develop a project as a team. How i share the working environment , database and reports

Here are the things I would set up:

- **Source control**
  This is an absolute must for more than one person.  Even with one person you will get many benefits.
- **An internal team wiki**
  If you write an e-mail with instructions, and the person you sent it to ever has to look at it again, or you ever have to dig up that e-mail and forward it to someone else, you've wasted time and money.  You could have written it up on an internal team wiki, and just sent out team-wide mails.  If you ever setup some shared server resource manually and didn't document it, then you've wasted that time.  Anything you learned in that experience *cannot* be replicated, and others will have to go through again.
  This is especially useful for things like server configuration instructions, server urls and ports, software setup instructions, document shares, new-hire setup instructions etc.
- **Continuous Integration**
  This is just a fancy way of saying that you need a fully scripted build.  With it, you will find out every day (or every check-in) if you've broken the build, and will be forced to fix it before other people are impacted.  With a VS environment, the script will usually consist of syncing code from source control and building a .sln file.  Fairly simple.
- **Automated database creation from scripts**
  This will make your life much easier when trying to replicate your changes across DBs.  It will also keep you from ever ending up with a broken shared environment - simply roll back to a previous known working version of the DB scripts, blow away the shared DB, and redeploy.  You can export scripts from an existing database using 1st party tools, such as SQL Server Management Studio, or 3rd party tools, such as RedGate's various SQL Server products.  Check these scripts into source control, then for every new change, create a patch script and check it into source control, instead of manually applying the change.
- **Continuous Deployment**
  This is just a fancy way of saying that you have a fully scripted deployment.  If deploying to a shared Dev or QA environment takes more than a single button click (or no clicks - you just check e-mail daily to see if the deploy succeeded), you're wasting a huge amount of time and money.  This is more of a pain to automate than Continuous Integration, but the pain is as bad or worse if you don't script this out, and execute it manually (between two to ten times in a single test pass).
- **A Good Test Team**
  You need this more than you need any of the rest of these.  A good test team will write up a test plan and think of scenarios you as a developer won't think of.  They will be more passionate (or at least diligent) about quality than anyone on your dev team.  If you have to come up with all the test cases for your testers, then hire new testers.  Or hire better testers to mentor your existing testers (assuming they're capable of learning).  With four developers, I'd hire at bare-minimum two *good* testers.  And get as many as your company will let you have :)

All of the automation and servers you set up will take time.  They will seem difficult to set up the first time you do it, but they pay huge dividends in the end.  Use any of these on one project and you might only break even.  Use any of them on two projects and you come out ahead.

I also recommend you have a private DB on each dev machine, and migrate code to a shared environment only when checking in.

Comment: As for personal recommendations, I've found TeamCity to be a good and simple Continuous Integration server (the free version works great for a small team with few projects), SVN to be a good and simple source repository (and it is free.  TFS is okay too, though not free).   I haven't found a piece of wiki software I'm 100% happy with yet.  There are dozens of them, and I've only used one internal application, and one abandoned piece of open source software (Flexwiki) :)

Comment: Personally I _love_ Jenkins for CI - and its .NET support is getting better with every release. ScrewTurnWiki is OK, not least as it's open-source and .NET, so configurable.

Comment: I've heard good things about Jenkins (it used to be Hudson, right?), though I've never used it.  Thanks for the recommendations